# Error while upgrading Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

When I tried to upgrade my current Ubuntu system (13.04) to latest one (13.10) the upgrade aborted with these errors.

```
Failed to fetch 
http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/account-plugins/account-plugin-facebook_0.11+13.10.20130802-0ubuntu1_all.deb 
403 Forbidden 
Failed to fetch 
http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tomboy/tomboy_1.15.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
403 Forbidden 
Failed to fetch 
http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-scope-tomboy/unity-scope-tomboy_0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1_all.deb 
403 Forbidden 
Failed to fetch 
http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/friends/friends-facebook_0.2.0+13.10.20130926-0ubuntu1_all.deb 
403 Forbidden
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a proxy server issue. Our college uses proxy server which filters the traffic using keywords. And apparently **facebook**, **tomboy** are in the list of those keywords.

I upgraded the system from my home network and everything went just fine!

Comment: @all : Please don't follow the above command. My system also got f**ked up :(. I managed to upgrade the system from tty though.

Comment: updated answer is OK - dangerous commands removed